# Do not target the element by css inside the particular div

Tags: html, css

I have below code :

```css
div:not(".cms-data") p{ font-size: 20px; line-height: 32px;}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
<div class="cms-data">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
</div>
```

I want to add `font-size 20px` and `line-height 32px` to the outer `p` but css should not target inside the `div`.

As this is sample code I have many elements like `ul, ol`, `h1 to h6` so I can not use class for it. I just want the css which is not target to the element in particular div.

I tried `css` like :

```
div:not(".cms-data") 
p{ font-size: 20px; line-height: 32px;}
```

But it is not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course this does not work, if the first paragraph is not inside a div itself - `div:not(".cms-data") p` still demands that it be a descendant of one, with the only restriction that that div must not have that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

Use "*" selector and ">" seletor to point to p.

```css
*:not(.cms-data) > p { 
  font-size: 20px; 
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
<div class="cms-data">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: this will not work for me as I wrote in my question I have many elements

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can use all " * " selector, please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You Can fix this for CSS methods which are as follows:-

```
p{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
 }

.cms-data p{
  font-size: unset;
  line-height: unset;
 }
```

or you also give properties to cms-data div as per your requirement.

Comment: this will not work for me as I wrote in my question I have many elements

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1:** You need to give that outside `<p>` inside another div without having class `.cms-data` like

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>   
</div>
<div class="cms-data">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>   
</div>
```

And in your CSS you need to remove the double quotes for the selector.

```
div:not(.cms-data) p{ font-size: 20px; line-height: 32px;}
```

**SOLUTION 2:** Otherwise you can have your HTML code as it is and change only your CSS like

```
*:not(.cms-data) > p{ font-size: 20px; line-height: 32px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case use Id for perticular P tag it is unique for every tag

```css
/*  use Id*/
#outerPTag{
font-size:20px;
line-height: 32px;
}

/* if u want u can use class also just put that class where u want to use 
.outerPTag{
font-size:20px;
line-height: 32px;
}

*/

/* Do whatever you want here */
div p{
font-size: unset;
color:blue;
}

.cms-data{
border:1px solid red;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<p id="outerPTag">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
<div class="cms-data">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: this will not work for me as I wrote in my question I have many elements

Answer (score 0):

try like this.. :not taken styles parent div

**HTML**

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>   
<div class="cms-data">
    <p class="not">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>   
</div>
```

**css**

```
p:not(.not){ font-size: 20px; line-height: 32px;}
```